# Problem in formatting result set in desired format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, formatting

I have devices which are installed in a different location with different area ID I am returning the device activity status of different areas on an hourly basis in the following format.

```
AreaId  |   UpdatedOn             | DeviceStatus
  1     | 2018-08-08 00:00:00.000 | Active
  1     | 2018-08-08 01:00:00.000 | Active
  1     | 2018-08-08 02:00:00.000 | Active
  2     | 2018-08-08 00:00:00.000 | Inactive
  2     | 2018-08-08 01:00:00.000 | Active
  2     | 2018-08-08 02:00:00.000 | Active
  3     | 2018-08-08 00:00:00.000 | Active
  3     | 2018-08-08 01:00:00.000 | Inactive
  3     | 2018-08-08 02:00:00.000 | Inactive
```

As its clearly visible that Device 1 was active throughout. Device 2 was not active from 00.00 to 01.00 Hrs 
and device 3 was not active from 01.00 to 02.00 and 02.00 to 03.00 Hrs.

I want to show this data in the following format.

***Status of devices for 8 August 2018 0:00 Hrs to 03:00 Hrs***

```
Areaid     | Status
1          | Active
2          | Not Active between 00:00 hrs to 01:00 hrs
3          | Not Active between 01:00 hrs to 02:00 hrs and  02:00 hrs to 03:00 hrs
```

for all the Areas.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `STUFF` function in subquery to get `DeviceStatus = 'Inactive'` row data, then `outer join` base on `AreaId` table

```
SELECT t2.AreaId, coalesce(Status,'Active') Status
FROM (
    SELECT distinct AreaId,DeviceStatus,
           STUFF((
             SELECT ' and ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),UpdatedOn,108) + ' hrs' + ' to ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEADD(HOUR,1,UpdatedOn),108) + ' hrs'
             FROM T tt
             WHERE tt.AreaId = t1.AreaId and tt.DeviceStatus =  t1.DeviceStatus
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
           ,1,4,'') Status

    FROM T t1
    WHERE DeviceStatus = 'Inactive'
) t1 RIGHT JOIN 
(
    SELECT distinct AreaId
    FROM T
) t2
on t1.AreaId = t2.AreaId
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24989b0d716f0bf3fd4918125423477b)

**Result**

```
AreaId  Status
1      Active
2      00:00 hrs to 01:00 hrs
3      01:00 hrs to 02:00 hrs and 02:00 hrs to 03:00 hrs
```

Comment: Not really. Its showig the partially correct result .
I have integrdated your code from line 508
Please have a look at the dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24bf3ab87a106b67877b20b985c9d841

Comment: also If a device is inactive from **1:00-2:00 and 2:00-3:00** hrs it should show **inactive from 1:00 to 3:00 hrs** and not **inactive from 1:00 to 2:00 hrs and inactive from 2:00 to 3:00 hrs**

Comment: I will appreciate if you can help me out on this.

Comment: @ThugsofHindustan But your expect result is `01:00 hrs to 02:00 hrs and 02:00 hrs to 03:00 hrs` so it was be` 01:00 hrs to to 03:00 hrs`?

Comment: and could you provide your expect result from this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24bf3ab87a106b67877b20b985c9d841

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using lag() function

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d0ae9d3deb71f6a0c70311b73a8215a7)

```
select id,concat('Not Active between ', format(cast(prevd as datetime),' hh:mm '), 'hrs to ', format(cast(d as datetime),' hh:mm '), 'hrs') from
(select *,
LAG (d, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY d) prevd,
LAG (p, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY d) prevp
from cte1 
)a where prevp<>'0' and p<>prevp
```

Output:

```
id  status
1   Not Active between  01:00 hrs to  02:00 hrs
2   Not Active between  01:00 hrs to  02:00 hrs
```